# SFMC - Lookup a DE and copy the results into another DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, ssjs

I am new to SSJS, I am trying some basic use cases, in this case my use case is to lookup a DE and copy the results in target DE, both DEs are having same data structure. Below is given my code, its throwing an error "There was an error Adding the row(s)." Request help on this to resolve.

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core","1");
  
  try{
    
var de1 = DataExtension.Init("Test733");
var de2 = DataExtension.Init("D1886280-262C-49B2-BBFD-C7BFE4FAD10B");
    
var exec = de1.Rows.Lookup(["fn"],["Sir"]);
  
for (var k in exec) {
var rslt = exec[k];
}
var exec2 = de2.Rows.Add(rslt);
    
  } catch(error) {
    Write(Stringify(error));
  }
</script>
```

[image: Source DE]

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you need to do this with SSJS and not SQL in Automation Studio?

Comment: I am learning SSJS so trying out simple usecases...

Comment: SSJS is indeed good to know. But you should apply it in relevant use cases. In your example here, both performance and the volume of data which SSJS is able to process is inferior to SQL. I can highly recommend you to go through the [SSJS bootcamp series here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?app=desktop&list=PL_o00w2Z5LYHT6jXdqjyT1Lt3JTqcwqm9) - with numerous examples where SSJS is relevant to use. Being a good engineer is also about making the right choices for applying the correct solution when faced with a challenge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A record in a DE has hidden attributes like `_CustomObjectKey` , `_CreatedDate` which  were generated by MC system and immutable. So you cannot use these retrieved attributes to add to the new DE (de2).

The line `var rslt = exec[k]` is including these values.

You can pull the remaining attribute values (from fn, ln, mm columns in your DE) , after that put them in an object then add to an array and add to the targeted DE.

Try something like this:

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core", "1.1");
var lst = []; //Init array

var de1 = DataExtension.Init('DE1 customer key');
var de2 = DataExtension.Init('DE2 customer key');
var data = de1.Rows.Lookup(["fn"], ['sir']);

if(data.length >0){
    for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
        var obj = {};
        obj['fn'] = data[i].fn;
        obj['ln'] = data[i].ln;
        obj['mm'] = data[i].mm;        
        lst.push(obj);
    }
}

// Add these rows to de2
var result = de2.Rows.Add(lst);

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! The code given has worked for me..